# css not displaying on my webpage

Tags: css

I have just uploaded my html squeeze page to my website via file manager in cpanel. That's lovely. But what's happening is, the "page" is not displaying my css or background images even tho I have uploaded the css file and images to the same folder as my html page.

The funny thing is, when I just "open" from the desktop my html page into my browser, EVERYTHING is displaying correctly. I can't seem to post my css file here..

Comment: can you paste in here the contents of the `<head>` tag of your HTML file, and also the contents of your CSS file.. it's sounds a lot like  a path issue.

Comment: @DannyHearnah have you noticed last line of questioner? O.o

Comment: To verify your css file is linked correctly with your page, just view source the page in Firefox and clicked the css file. It should not display 404 not found.

Comment: @AspiringAqib i did, but i assumed that the OP was trying to upload the file.. that's why i used the keywords "paste"

Comment: @SudipPal must I use firefox for that? as I only have chrome...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look at the source in chrome you right-click on the page and choose 'view page source' or 'view source' (or something sortalike, my chrome isn't english, so I'm guessing the translation.)

Then look for the head part in your page source and post the link to the css file here.
it'll probably look like something this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/css/[nameofyourstylesheet].css" />
```

My first guess would be that your css file is linked to the css file on your harddrive.

Comment: <title>Mind Experiments</title>
<!-- Main stylesheet for the layout -->
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. But your stylesheet is linked the way it should be. Could you give us the url of your site? Because we need a bit more info to find the cause of your problem.

Comment: Here is the squeeze page for my website: 

http://www.thegazillionaire.com/concrete/dcsxconcrete.html

Comment: as you can see it displays fine, except there is no boarder/background displaying from my css file/images

Comment: and you've also uploaded the images folder (with the images in it) to your host?
Did you use a a webbased ftp client? If so did you transfer the images in binary mode? (If not that could be the problem, if your ftp program doesn't let you choose it probably was uploaded in the correct way)

Comment: yes i uploaded the images, background jpg, bot jpg, mid png, top jpg along with the style css into the same folder as my html page.

Comment: I see you managed to fix it. What was the problem? / what did you do to make it work?